# What is the new review function before posting a questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I asked a question on Stackoverflow and this time I couldn't just send the question as the button said:

> Review question

I then thought, ok, I'll see a preview of my question (only). Like when you review your basket before sending it in an online shop.

But I was presented with the same page (at least it looked like it) with edit functionality and all that. Only the button changed to:

> Post your question

What is the purpose of this new function?

---

<sub>I hope this is not a duplicate. I've searched for questions with review, but there comes up a lot of other stuff related mostly to the review queue.</sub>

Comment: This process only exists on Stack Overflow, so I'm going to move this to MSO. :D